# VB NET - CopyDirectory only copies files? Why?

Tags: vb.net, copy

I have been trying to do this seemingly simple task for a while now, but no luck. Here is some pieces of code I'm using...

```
Dim SDPath As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim ContentPath As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim RPXName As String = TextBox4.Text
Dim Copy_To_Dir As String = SDPath & RPXName

Dim Copy_To_Dir As String = SDPath & RPXName

    'copy any subdirs from ContentDir to SD:\RPXName

    For Each ContentDirSub In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(ContentPath, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(ContentDirSub, Copy_To_Dir, True)
    Next
```

This should create the sub directories in the specific path. Where am I going wrong here??? I've been scouring examples but found nothing.  I also want this to copy the contents of the sub directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it isn't working but you could try to make sure that the path you are copying to is a correct directory path. The below code combines the path into a correct path name.

```
Dim Copy_To_Dir As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(SDPath & RPXName)
```

You also don't need to write that twice.

Is there any errors appearing?

Comment: i solved it in the wee hours of this morning, haven't got around to replying to this, but that is what did it, the Path.Combine solved it.